# ERROR: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to Integer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm having a hard time with this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to Integer

The code seem to work fine, I used it on others but the only difference is the primary key I'm using, for this one I used an integer while on the others I used `nvarchar` for their primary key. Thanks for any answers in advance.

Here is my code:

```
     Private Sub deleteIndv()

    Dim result
    Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

        result = MsgBox(" Are You Sure You Want to Delete the Selected Row ? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

        TextBox2.Text = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString

        '  Try

        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then

            Exit Sub

        Else

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

                con.Open()

            End If

            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = " & id

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow)

            MsgBox(" Record Successfully Deleted! ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        End If

        'Catch ex As Exception

        ' MsgBox(" Error Deleting Records! ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

        ' End Try

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    End Using

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        con.Close()

    End If
```

Comment: What is the value of id?

Comment: I didn't quite get you, as what i've understand on your question this is the value of the id "Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value" while on sql the value of the ID i used is an auto increment value

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: ohh i totally forgot LOL.. thanks for reminding

Comment: I mean what is the actual value returned by this? Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

Comment: ohh..the selected row on the datagridview which then compares by the commandtext. id = Id_indv

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by SQL.
Are you sure that the line below actually returns and integer?:

```
Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
```

Test it first (something along the example below):

```
 Dim g As String
 Try
      Dim l As Integer = Integer.Parse(g)
      'If successful then save action'

 Catch ex As Exception
      'Warn about error'

 End Try
```

Comment: I think.. it doesn't. after i run the program and displayed the error i saw in "autos" that the "id" i set for the "indv_id" to be stored was not the indv_id but the 1st column on sql table data -_-

Comment: well i only encountered a problem here. on other delete functions I created which the Id was a nvarchar my code worked perfectly as what i've mentioned above.

Comment: If you want to save an integer you should make should it is an integer..Testing for it and handling any associated error is the first step. It might very well me that a character is encountered that can not be successfully converted to integer: eg.: an , (comma) when a . (dot) is expected, nbsp (non breaking space [think char(160)] when a space is expected, etc.

Comment: the error popping is "Incorrect syntax near 'Tellering'" the " Tellering is part of the whole project name that is " Branch Tellering System" which is also the first column of my tbl Indv_Reports where the PK is Indv_Id.  supposedly what should've happen was the " Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value " will hold the selected row in my DGV then "  cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = " & id " should locate the PK which is Id_indv then proceed w/ the process.. but thats not whats happening

Comment: what do the quick view for the following return: "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = " & id. It should return something like to following to run with error: "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = 101 ". If it return "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = peter" it will generate and error because you stated that id_indv is and integer field.

Comment: it returned a string and not the PK which is the integer .. it was from the first column of the table which was the  "project title" and it was a nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. the problem was with this "Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value" i just specified the exact cell number of Id_indv on the table i changed it from (0) to (18) the column where my PK was located. thank you for those who helped me solve this.
Here is the working code for others reference:

```
    Dim result
    Dim id As String = Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells(18).Value

    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

        result = MsgBox(" Are You Sure You Want to Delete the Selected Row ? ", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

        '  Try

        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then

            Exit Sub

        Else

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

                con.Open()

            End If

            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM IndvReports WHERE Id_indv = " & id

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView2.CurrentRow)

            MsgBox(" Record Successfully Deleted! ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

            cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        End If

        'Catch ex As Exception

        ' MsgBox(" Error Deleting Records! ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

        ' End Try

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    End Using

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        con.Close()

    End If
```